# Why does SmtpClient.SendAsync hang?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I am using `SmtpClient.SendAsync` (C#) to send emails in ASP.NET web applications and services. The web application/service runs on Windows Server 2012 R2 using IIS 8.

There are times where the call to `SendAsync` hangs up and does not appear to send the mail message asynchronously, so the calling thread blocks. This behavior seems to be sporadic. I cannot replicate the problem in a testing environment. This is especially problematic when sending the email as a result of a call to a web method because the timeout is 60 seconds (I'm using `SendAsync` for this very reason so the client doesn't experience any time delay).

Here is my code snippet.

```
SmtpClient client;
MailMessage msg;

public void SendMail()
{
    try
    {
        client = new SmtpClient("smtpAddress@mydomain.com");
        msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Subject = "Test";
        msg.Body = "This is the body";
        msg.From = "noreply@example.com";
        msg.To.Add("me@example.com");

        client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(sendCompletedCallback);
        client.SendAsync(msg, "Test");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error
    }
}

private void sendCompletedCallback(object send, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Log error
    }
    else if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        // Log cancellation
    }
    else
    {
        // Log success
    }

    client.Dispose();
    msg.Dispose();
}
```

Why does the call to `SendAsync` hang and block the calling thread at times?

Comment: That really shouldn't be the case. Why do you say that it blocks your calling thread? Run it in `Release` mode and see whether it still blocks. behavior is different for async call when you debug using breakpoint. compiler behind the scene does stuff to give you a feeling that you are debugging a normal method. mail is not sending could be an issue with your SMTP server.

Comment: I've found a few other instance of it behaving this way online, with no satisfactory answer. The most commonly used workaround seems to be to wrap it in a call to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: @Rahul I know that it blocks because I have additional logging after the call to SendAsync in my web service and I do not see these log messages. I only ever deploy to production in release mode.

Comment: http://www.codefrenzy.net/2012/01/30/how-asynchronous-is-smtpclient-sendasync/ seems to suggest that if you are sending multiple messages, you have to wait for the previous one to finish before you can send the next one. Subsequent  calls will block until previous one completes.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx
There might be two case, either it is not waiting for **e-mail transmission to complete before attempting to send another e-mail message**
or 
***recipients is invalid***

Comment: If either contributed to my problem, why would the calling thread block if the message is truly sent asynchronously? I create a new instance of the SmtpClient class every time I send an email, so I shouldn't be receiving any conflict of sending another message before the first finishes. I also do not receive an SmtpException, which should be thrown if one of the recipients is invalid.

Comment: If you have a GUI where sending email have a wait time, then using `client.SendAsync` make sense, because it will not freeze the UI. In case you are doing from batch job or console application, then I do not see any benefit of using `client.SendAsync`. You can test above cases in your code. At least MSDN gives these reason for exception.